# Enabling Console tab in Version Control section of PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How can I enable a Console tab in PhpStorm if it is not displaying?
Currently I have only Local Changes and Log tabs

Answer (score 1):

The `Console` tab automatically opens when you perform a VCS operation.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, but there are only push and commit action.
My real question was - how can I see all operations that PhpStorm execute like, for instance, comparing with branch or diff between commits